# Aggregation in pandas dataframe on two separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I  am trying to do aggregation on fields `cat1, cat2, cat3` on the following DataFrame. I need to `count the number of trials` and the `number of unique subjects` in each group. The code below does find the number of trials correct but the number of subject is not correct.

```
mydata = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
         ['Adam', 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L],
         ['Adam', 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L],
         ['Adam', 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L],
         ['Adam', 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L],
         ['Adam', 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L],
         ['Adam', 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L],
         ['Bob', 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L],
         ['Bob', 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L],
         ['Bob', 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L],
         ['Bob', 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L],
         ['Bob', 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L],
         ['Bob', 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L]], dtype=object),
         columns = ['ID','trial','cat1','cat2','cat3']
        )

grouped = mydata.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']).agg(['count'])

grouped.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   cat1  cat2  cat3     ID  trial
                     count  count
0     1     1     1      3      3
1     1     1     2      1      1
2     1     2     1      2      2
3     1     2     3      3      3
4     1     3     1      1      1
5     2     2     3      2      2
```

The result that I am expecting is :

```
   cat1  cat2  cat3  trial  ID
0     1     1     1      3   2
1     1     1     2      1   1
2     1     2     1      2   1
3     1     2     3      3   1
4     1     3     1      1   1
5     2     2     3      2   2
```

Comment: Can you explain *how* you expect to get that data?  Why, for instance, does the first row have 2 for ID/count and 3 for trial/count?  Also, the formatting of your output examples is confusing, and it's not clear where the column headers are supposed to line up.  Please clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `aggregate` on `ID` with `pd.Series.nunique` and get `count` from `trail`

```
In [215]: (mydata.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
                .agg({'ID': pd.Series.nunique, 'trial': 'count'})
                .reset_index())
Out[215]:
   cat1  cat2  cat3  trial  ID
0     1     1     1      3   2
1     1     1     2      1   1
2     1     2     1      2   1
3     1     2     3      3   1
4     1     3     1      1   1
5     2     2     3      2   2
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking too, but I don't see how the poster expected to get this from the original code.

Comment: @JohnGalt, Is there a way to know the 'IDs' also? I  mean, which IDs corresponds to the unique counts for each group.